# Python os.rename() for files within multiple subfolders in a parent directory

Tags: python, xml, directory, rename

**File Structure** 
I have a parent directory, called `test_folder`, which has several (approximately 600) subfolders in it. Each subfolder contains the following:


- Always a `metadump.xml` file

- Either a `.pdf`, `.pptx`, `.xls`, or `.docx` file

**Goal** 
I would like to rename the respective `.pdf`, `.pptx`, `.xls`, or `.docx` file in each subfolder of my parent directory (`test_folder`) based on the *title* information from the `.xml` file within the same subfolder, named `banana` in this example below.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\**\\Downloads\\test_folder"):
    for file in files:
        if file == 'metadump.xml':
            filename = os.path.join(root, file) 

            # READ XML FILE TO OBTAIN 'TITLE' INFORMATION
            with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as xml_file:
                contents = xml_file.read()
                title = re.search('<dc:title rsfieldtitle="Title" rsembeddedequiv="Name" rsfieldref="8" rsfieldtype="0">(.+?)</dc:title>', contents).group(1)
                print(title) #AS A CHECK FOR SUCCESSFUL TITLE EXTRACTION

    # GOING THROUGH FILES AGAIN TO FIND NON-XML FILE
    for file in files:
        if file != 'metadump.xml':
            print(file) #CHECKING THE CORRECT FILE TO BE RENAMED IS SELECTED
            src = os.path.join(root, file) #ORIGINAL SOURCE PATH
            dst = os.path.join(root, title)#NEW DESTINATION PATH
            os.rename(src, dst) #TO RENAME FILES IN THE SUBFOLDER TO THE TITLE
```

After running this, I receive the following:

`Project Alpha` <-- The correct title has been extracted from the XML

`foobar.pdf`    <-- The correct 'other' file in the subfolder has been selected for renaming

`[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\**\\Downloads\\test_folder\\banana\\foobar.pdf' -> 'C:\\**\\Downloads\\test_folder\\banana\\Project Alpha'`

 I am unsure why I am unable to rename the other file, `foobar.pdf` with the 'title' that was extracted from the `.XML` file in the same subfolder.

**Example of Desired Output** 

 In `test_folder` parent directory, in `banana` subfolder we have:

Given:

- `foobar.pdf` (generic file name)

- `metadump.xml` (in this file, the title: *Project Alpha* can be extracted)

Result: 

- `Project_Alpha.pdf` (the pdf name has been changed here)

- `metadump.xml`

Thank you in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: You only go into the rename part of your code if the file == "metadatadump.xml" (line 5) so the file never becomes anything other than the .xml file. Unindent lines 11-15 and code should work as long as the xml file is checked first? Sorry I have no time to test, but that's a good start.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but is there any particular reason you have all those `else: pass`es? Else clauses aren't mandatory in Python. If you don't need them, you can simply leave them out.

Comment: Hi @TD-Asker My thought process is that, I know each subfolder contains a "metadump.xml" file from which I get the "title" from. Afterwards, I am trying to rename the OTHER file in the subfolder to this "title", not the "metadump.xml" file itself. Thanks!

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, I was commenting to say why your initial code would not work. Have you tried os.rename for one specific file from your python environment to check you have the correct permissions etc.? Also make sure you are renaming the file from foobar.pdf to Project_Alpha.pdf - it looks like you may be missing the file extension?

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is all messed up.  You should first read the xml, then rename your other files.  See below.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:/**/Downloads/test_folder"):
    for file in files:
        if file == 'metadump.xml':
            filename = os.path.join(root, file) 

            with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_xml:
                contents = f_xml.read()
                title = re.search('<dc:title rsfieldtitle="Title" rsembeddedequiv="Name" rsfieldref="8" rsfieldtype="0">(.+?)</dc:title>', contents).group(1)
                print(title) #AS A CHECK FOR SUCCESSFUL TITLE EXTRACTION

# NOW GO THROUGH YOUR FILES IN CURRENT DIRECTORY AGAIN
    for file in files:
        if file != 'metadump.xml':
            src = os.path.join(root, file)
            dst = os.path.join(root, title)
            os.rename(src, dst) #TO RENAME FILES IN THE SUBFOLDER TO THE TITLE
```

Or, better yet:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:/**/Downloads/test_folder"):
    # find xml file
    xmlFile = [r for r in files if r[-3:]=='xml']
    filename = os.path.join(root, xmlFile)

    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_xml:
        contents = f_xml.read()
        title = re.search('<dc:title rsfieldtitle="Title" rsembeddedequiv="Name" rsfieldref="8" rsfieldtype="0">(.+?)</dc:title>', contents).group(1)
        print(title) #AS A CHECK FOR SUCCESSFUL TITLE EXTRACTION

# NOW RENAME FILES
[os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, title)) for f in files if f[-3:]!='xml']
```

I do not see where you are setting the file extension, perhaps you need to have os.rename(file, title + '.jpg') or something.

Comment: I am seeing the following error: `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'foobar.pdf' -> 'Project Alpha'`. On a sidenote, just want to add we need a `:` for the second `for file in files` line. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for catching the missing colon.  Your error makes sense.  You need to add the root path...see edits.

Comment: Regarding your note about file extensions, the issue is that I am working with several different possible file types that I'd like to rename. Perhaps I can rename by using some form of `title.*`? Regarding your first solution, I am seeing the following: `[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:/**/Downloads/test_folder\\banana\\foobar.pdf' -> 'Project Alpha'`

Comment: Oh good grief.  Can't believe I did that.  You need to specify the path for the destination file as well.  See edits.

Comment: I believe I am following your intent. After receiving the following, `[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:/**/Downloads/test_folder\\banana\\foobar.pdf' -> 'C:/**/Downloads/test_folder\\banana\\Project Alpha'`, I wonder if the inconsistent "/ \" in the paths are causing the issue or if this is another matter?

Comment: I've updated my original question to reflect my current stance. Thanks for your help thus far!